# Solid tyres for child's tricycle

Tags: tire, vintage, children, raleigh

Is it still possible to purchase solid white rubber tyres? I need some for a Raleigh Tiger child's tricycle I am renovating the size in the side wall states 12 x 7/8 there is 300mm also on the side wall.

[image: Stock photo]

Comment: Welcome to the bikes SE! We do tend to work differently from other discussion fora. In particular, the FAQ explicitly says no product recommendations. This question seems a little close to that type of question. Moreover, it might be better answered by approaching a local bike shop.

Comment: Solid rubber tires are hard to find.  Generally you must purchase the entire wheel (if you can even find that).

Comment: One avenue I know exists for this kind of thing is solid tire type material you buy in lengths, cut to size, and glue on. 7/8" is one of the sizes it comes in if I recall correctly. I've seen penny farthing restoration type sites selling it. It's more of an antiques thing than a bikes thing, i.e. those are the sorts of businesses that seem to have it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going for an original-spec rebuild, I'd absolutely stay with white tyres on that bike.   However if you just want a kid to ride it, then there's no reason to stay with solid or even white.

3 modern tyres will look fine, and will be more comfortable than a solid tyre.  You can sometimes find them in white, or even other colours.

If the rim has no valve hole, then you would have to drill one.   Also, depends if the rim has a hook for the tyre bead.... without that a modern tyre won't secure to the rim.

Comment: I'm reasonably certain that the rims have no beads, and regular pneumatic tires would pop off.   Of course, you could always try lace-ups.  (Good luck finding those!)

Comment: @DanielRHicks mmm yeah that would be likely.  Perhaps relacing all three wheels onto more-modern rims would be a good longterm solution.  Depends if its going to be ridden for real, or just displayed.

Comment: I've worked on a number of kids bikes with solid rubber tires.  I've never seen one with rims that would accept normal pneumatic tires.  In general the cross-section of the rim is a simple arc.

Comment: Low pressure tires have been used with hookless rims for ages. I think they would be fine here, too, if you can find a matching size.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Perhaps such an arc would accept a tubular? But I fear there may be none at 12 inch.